# Solving Nonlinear system of equations in Mathematica (wolfram)

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions, wolfram-language

I'm Trying to solve a System of equations in Mathmatica with the Function of NSolve

The Code should represent a Mass Balance of A factory, in one of the Flows im trying to change the Conc. of the Solvent and it work up to a certian point

The Code that works is :

```
NSolve[{
  m1 == m4 + m5,
  m1*0.952 == m4 + m5*0.454,
  m1*0.048 == m5*0.546,
  x6MgCl2 + x6H2O == 1,
  0.255*x6MgCl2 == x6Mg,
  0.745*x6MgCl2 == x6Cl2,
  x11H2O + x11Br2 + x11Cl2 == 1,
  m5 + m7 + m9 + m10 + m12 == m6 + m11,
  m5*0.072 == m6*x6Mg,
  m5*0.454 + m7 + m10 == m6*x6H2O + m11*x11H2O,
  m5*0.474 == m11*x11Br2,
  m9 + m12 == m6*x6Cl2 + m11*x11Cl2,
  m6 == m7 + m8,
  m6*x6MgCl2 == m8*0.056,
  m6*x6H2O == m7 + m8*0.944,
  m11 == m12 + m13 + 8163.265,
  m11*x11Br2 == m13*0.030 + 8000,
  m11*x11H2O == m13*0.970 + 163.265,
  m11*x11Cl2 == m12,
  x11Cl2 == x11Br2*0.0311,
  m1 >= 0, m4 >= 0, m5 >= 0, m6 >= 0, m7 >= 0, m8 >= 0, m9 >= 0, 
  m10 >= 0, m11 >= 0, m12 >= 0, m13 >= 0, x11H2O >= 0, x11Br2 >= 0, 
  x11Cl2 >= 0, x6MgCl2 > 0, x6H2O > 0, x6Mg > 0, x6Cl2 > 0
  }, {m1, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13, x11H2O, x11Br2, 
  x11Cl2, x6MgCl2, x6H2O, x6Mg, x6Cl2}, Reals]
```

the Answer that i get is :

```
{{m1 -> 192590., m4 -> 175660., m5 -> 16931., m6 -> 2.0519*10^5, 
  m7 -> 119830., m8 -> 85365., m9 -> 3561.4, m10 -> 73874., 
  m11 -> 9251.3, m12 -> 249.58, m13 -> 838.41, x11H2O -> 0.10556, 
  x11Br2 -> 0.86747, x11Cl2 -> 0.026978, x6MgCl2 -> 0.023297, 
  x6H2O -> 0.9767, x6Mg -> 0.0059407, x6Cl2 -> 0.017356}}
```

However, if im Changing Eq 14 & 15 in order to reduce the Conc. I dont get an answer (if i do the oppsite i do get an answer)

For Example :
Changing the Eqution to :

```
m6*x6MgCl2 == m8*0.05,
m6*x6H2O == m7 + m8*0.95,
```

dont give me an answer, Changing it to

```
m6*x6MgCl2 == m8*0.06,
m6*x6H2O == m7 + m8*0.94,
```

does give an answer

I need all The Values to be Positive and all the x Represent Mass Fraction and need to be between 0 to 1

Please Help Me with that :(

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When I run your `NSolve[...]` as given I get a warning "Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1..." which I believe is saying that there are redundant equations. For example, if I add equation 2 to equation 3 I get equation 1. Redundant equations and constants with decimal points can cause all kinds of problems.  If I change 0.056 to 56/1000 and do the same with all your other decimal constants and run the result then it tells me there is no solution. I have tried to find other redundant equations and failed. Can you edit your post to show the minimal not redundant set of equations too?